# Mailing code giving an error

Tags: php, email

I am new to php & have tried out some code in php for sending mail to user by some simple means, i am facing some issues as code giving a error..!! please help me.

**php**

```
$to      =  ' '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' ';
        $subject = 'Your vault number';
        $message = 'Your vault number is '". $_SESSION['vault_no'] ."' ';
        $headers = 'From: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: innovation@miisky.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What error? Please be more specific

Comment: sorry sir..!! its throwing a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in your code
$to = ' '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' ';

Comment: DId you check it has values?

Comment: session_start(); ?

Comment: yes sir!! i have specified session_start(); at beginning of my code!

Comment: I only faced this Problem when I either forgot to start the session, the values where emty or they where an array instead of a string.

Comment: Is there an error in  $to = ' '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' '; part of code.! its pointing error here

Comment: Oh yeah, I was blind. That's your problem :) $to      =  $_SESSION['email'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Syntax error in your string assignment:

```
$to      =  ' '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' ';
              ^ here                   ^ and here
```

You don't even need delimiters as part of your final string,

```
$to      =  $_SESSION['email'];
```

is enough, as `$_SESSION['email']` already is a string.

Comment: Damn you beat me about a few seconds :)

Comment: @TechTreeDev Yes :) BTW, OP doesn't need delimiters there, in fact I think this would break his `mail()` function if you add `'`  to the address

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem ist that you have a syntax error  on your $to variable.

```
$to      =  ' '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' ';
```

Change them to

```
$to      =  $_SESSION['email'];;
```